# External jar's Spring configuration *.xml file is not found

Tags: java, xml, spring, classpath, filenotfoundexception

I have a jar x which has a class like

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "/WEB-INF/assembly/appconfig.xml" })
public class DSPPlatformCommonSiteDefConfig {}
```

Now in a different project altogether, I have added this jar as a dependency.

And import this class like:

```
@Configuration
@Import(DSPPlatformCommonSiteDefConfig.class)
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
```

}

So basically, I am using Spring configuration file of a jar in my project.

But when I run my application I get this error:

Message: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/assembly/appconfig.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [WEB-INF/assembly/appconfig.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/assembly/appconfig.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I do not understand why it is looking in the classpath. And even if it does, the jar IS in my classpath.

Comment: Hi Vishal, I cannot change this External jar.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be at the path declaration for the [location](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html#locations--) inside the `@ImportResource` annotation. The path should be the URI of the file which must not be the one that you declared.

An example could be the following path:

```
@ImportResource(locations={ "file:com/yourProjectName/assembly/appconfig.xml" })
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.
Yes! 
That seems right. But since it is an external jar, I cannot change it.

Comment: Do you have the right permissions to decompile the jar classes?